# Fix linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to get a linear-gradient style to work. I am targeting the 4 sides of a div separately, each with its own linear-gradient value. I can't seem to get them all to display properly together, so I have tried to isolate them.

They all seem to work individually, but as I add them together one at a time, something breaks down in the display, and not just with the linear-gradient. I've had the border and padding disappear on me when those properties were under the linear-gradient properties. I resolved that issue by moving them above the linear-gradient properties.

In the code below, the gradient from right to left works fine, but the colors are on the left-to-right gradient. (The other two sides are currently commented out). This is only one of many problems I'm experiencing when I try to combine them. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.inset-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(31, 122, 122, 0.7), rgba(235, 250, 250, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)),
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(31, 122, 122, 0.7), rgba(235, 250, 250, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  /*
  linear-gradient(rgba(31, 122, 122, 0.7), rgba(235, 250, 250, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))
  linear-gradient(to top, rgba(31, 122, 122, 0.7), rgba(235, 250, 250, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  */
}               

.inset {
  max-width: 92%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;    
}
```

```html
<div class="inset-container">
  <div class="inset">
    <h3>Included in this month’s newsletter:</h3>
    <p><a href="#Safety" class="links">Safety First: Prescription Safety Glasses</a>  - Find out who pays that bill in this months Safety First.</p>        
    <p><a href="#Flux" class="links">Flux</a> - Which way to the problem? Splitters messing with your head? Read this Flux tip for clarification.</p>
    <p><a href="#MDUMaps" class="links">Tool Tip: MDU Maps</a> - Hey, My maps are blank in Divisional Viewer! Well, you’re doing it wrong!</p>
    <p><a href="#XM1" class="links">Tool Tip: XM1 Plant Design Maps</a> - Why does all the cool stuff go to the service department?</p>
    <p><a href="#Battery" class="links">The Battery Balancer</a> - How much more can we fit in that cabinet?!</p>
    <p><a href="#DMTicketing" class="links">DM Ticketing</a> - SASQ Watch because Big Bird was taken.</p>
    <p><a href="#ONX" class="links">Viavi’s ONX-630</a> - Initializing…… That’s an inside joke! You’ll get it later or will you? Just read this for a quick overview of the new meter.</p>
    <p><a href="#Tales"class="links">Tales From The Field</a> - Hello, Hello, HELLO! It’s ok to share with the group! Send us your pics!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is getting displayed incorrectly? From what I can see, your gradients are behaving as expected. The left to right colours are "off" because you are overlaying one gradient on top of another.

Comment: Thanks Fluffy, you are correct, I overlooked the effect that the alpha channel was having on the other 3 sides. I'm sure I will continue to make silly beginner mistakes for quite some time, but I really appreciate your response!